# Google map AppにAPIキーを追加できない

Tags: swift, cocoapods, swiftui

以下のURLのドキュメントにしたがってAppDelegate.swiftにGMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("YOUR_API_KEY")を追加しようとしますが、Use of unresolved identifier 'GMSPlacesClient'のエラーが出てきます。
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/get-api-key

cocoapodsでのInstallがうまくいっていないのでしょうか。何回か試しましたが、どうもうまくいきません。
GMSPlacesClientの初期化ができないからか、地図もまっさらになり、よくクラッシュします。
こちらの対処方法をご教授頂けますでしょうか。

podfileの中身は以下の通りです。

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
target 'アプリ名' do
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'AWSAppSync'
  # Pods for アプリ名

 # target 'アプリ名Tests' do
   # inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
 # end

 # target 'アプリ名UITests' do
    # Pods for testing
 # end

end
```

クラッシュするswiftのファイルは以下の通りです。

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

struct GoogleMapView: UIViewRepresentable {
let marker : GMSMarker = GMSMarker()

/// Creates a `UIView` instance to be presented.
func makeUIView(context: Self.Context) -> GMSMapView {
    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
    // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6.0)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)

    return mapView
}

/// Updates the presented `UIView` (and coordinator) to the latest
/// configuration.
func updateUIView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, context: Self.Context) {
    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20)
    marker.title = "Sydney"
    marker.snippet = "Australia"
    marker.map = mapView
}

}

struct GoogleMapView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GoogleMapView()
    }
}
```

よろしくお願い致します。